# LESS: having feedback about coding errors

Tags: debugging, less

[Less2css.org](http://less2css.org) has a very useful function that give feedback in realtime about possible mistakes in writing LESS code.

When I write LESS code in my editor and then go back to browser to test my page, if I done an error simply entire file is ignored and I display website like it does not have any stylesheet applied on it.
Is there a way to have some sort of feedback about possible LESS coding errors?

Thank you.

Comment: are you using `development` mode? [maybe this could help you](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10543145/2113185)

Comment: Ohhh right!! that's the solution! Thank you. :-)
I can't accept your answer because it's a comment... maybe could be useful that you answer my question (for other people) so I'll be able to accept it, am I wrong? :-)

Comment: I think the standard procedur would involve closing your question as a duplicate to the other one. And if it solved your problem ... you can upvote the useful answer there. Best!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Martin, `development` mode is the solution.